# How to fill a color to a donut SVG path by percentage by starting from left side?

Tags: svg, clip-path

I have a donut SVG path. It must start from left side to fill a color and must end at the right side and it must fill by percentage.

See this:

[image: this]
<sub>(source: [eksiup.com](https://eksiup.com/images/93/38/wi210390d95j.png))</sub>

I tried to achieve this rotating clipPath like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 92 100">
<defs>
  <clipPath id="knobMask">
      <path style="fill: #ff554e;" d="
            M 17.72, 74.28
           a 40, 40,0, 1, 1, 56.56, 0
           l 4.25, 4.25
           a 46, 46, 0, 1, 0-65.06 ,0 Z" />
</clipPath>
</defs>
<g>
<g id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1">
  <g id="Path_34688-6" data-name="Path 34688-6">
    />
  </g>
  <path d="M17.72,74.28a40,40,0,1,1,56.56,0l4.25,4.25a46,46,0,1,0-65.06,0Z" />

  <g clip-path="url(#knobMask)" transform="rotate(-45,45,45)">
    <path style="fill: #ff554e;" d="M 17.72,74.28
            a 40,40,0,1,1,56.56,0
            l 4.25,4.25
            a 46,46,0,1,0-65.06,0Z" />
  </g>
</g>
```

But no luck. How can I fill a color to this path starting from left side by percentage?

[Here is the JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0dvu2L43/)

Basically I want this:

[image: this]
<sub>(source: [eksiup.com](https://eksiup.com/images/99/68/qs2104533kj7.png))</sub>

Comment: There is a simpler way to achieve this. You simplify the path to ` d="M 17.72,74.28a 40,40,0,1,1,56.56,0"` and use `fill="none"` and `stroke="10"` for example. For the red path you are using the same `d` as before and you use `stroke-dasharray` to reduce the apparent length of the path. If you are using this `d` the total length of the path is 188.53 so you can use 188.53 / 2 = 94.265 : `stroke-dasharray=94.265"`

Comment: Thank you your your answer. That very helped me but `stroke-dasharray` attribute is creating dashes and I don't want that. I want to use single line on black path. Here's the latest [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z6jhtL48)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've commented there is a simpler way to achieve this. You simplify the path to `d="M 17.72,74.28a 40,40,0,1,1,56.56,0"` and use fill="none" and stroke="10" for example. For the red path you are using the same d as before and you use stroke-dasharray to reduce the apparent length of the path. If you are using this d the total length of the path is 188.53 so you can use 188.53 / 2 = 94.265 : stroke-dasharray=94.265"

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 92 100" width="200">
<defs>
      <path id="base" fill="none" stroke-width="10" d="
            M 17.72, 74.28
           a 40, 40,0, 1, 1, 56.56, 0" />
 </defs> 
  <use xlink:href="#base" stroke="black"  />
  <use xlink:href="#base" stroke="#ff554e" stroke-dasharray="94.265"  />

  </svg>
```

In the next example I'm using javascript to calculate the value of the dash and the value of the gap. Please use the input type range to change the values.

```js
let totallength=base.getTotalLength();

itr.addEventListener("input",()=>{
let newSDA = (Number(itr.value)*totallength) / 100;
let gap = totallength - newSDA

red.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke-dasharray",`${newSDA} ${gap}`)
})
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<p><input id="itr" type="range"  /></p>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 92 100" width="200">
<defs>
      <path id="base" fill="none" stroke-width="10" d="
            M 17.72, 74.28
           a 40, 40,0, 1, 1, 56.56, 0" />
 </defs> 
  <use xlink:href="#base" stroke="black"  />
  <use xlink:href="#base" id="red" stroke="#ff554e" stroke-dasharray="94.265"  />

  </svg>
```

Comment: Think that circle is 360 degree. If I want to set red path to 45 degree over black path, How do I do that. Because this method is very similar to what I want but this method creates dashes.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please take a loo and let me know if this is what you need

Comment: That is Mind-blowing! That's a great solution. Thank you so much. Worked like a charm!

Comment: How did you calculated the `total length of the path`? I'm still in learning process.  SVG and path tag is so complicated...

Comment: The first line of code in the javascript is doing it: `let totallength=base.getTotalLength();` where base is the path in the defs that is being used for both the black and the red arc

Comment: How can I calculate this myself? because I'm using NodeJS so can't use this in my project

Comment: You should ask this as a different question